# Is there a way to make a bash script process messages that have been sent to it using the write command

Tags: linux, bash, debian

Is there a way to make a bash script process messages that have been sent to it using the "write" command? So for example, if a user wants to activate a feature in my script, could I make it so that they can send the script a command using the write command?

One possible method I thought of was to configure logging for a screen session and then have the bash script parse text through there, but I'm not sure if there would be a simpler or more efficient way to tackle this

EDIT: I was thinking as an alternative solution I could use a named pipe. I'm worried that it would break though if the tmp partition gets filled up completely (not sure if this would impact write as well?). I'm going to be running this script on a shared box, and every once in a while someone will completely fill up the /tmp partition and then just leave it like that until people start complaining

Comment: Why would you want to send it using the write command?

Comment: @123 would there be a better way of doing this? I'm trying to make it so a user can trigger functions in a script without having to have r/w access to the script itself. I was thinking I could also just have the user enter commands into a file that the script would watch although I felt that this option might be a bit more versatile

Comment: What do you mean by activate a feature in your script ? Is the script continuously running? Can you give an example of something the script would do?

Comment: You could do this with a fifo, but I like the write idea better.  The fifo can be removed.

Comment: @123 I would have a script running in a screen session that would send SOAP requests to another server whenever a user sends a command to it  using the write command, etc. The users would not normally have access to the server that would be processing the SOAP requests, so this will allow them to make it execute some rudimentary functions (managing and unmanaging monitoring for devices) without having to have accounts on the server itself

Comment: Anything requiring asynchronous reading/writing is going to require some buffering, whether that is an OS-managed memory buffer or a file in /tmp. Use a named pipe or a UNIX socket instead of trying to reimplement them using (pseudo)terminals.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you are trying to really circumvent a poor unix command to ask it something it was not specified for. From the man page (emphasize mine):

> The write utility allows you to communicate with other users, by **copying
>        lines from your terminal to theirs**

That means that write is intended to copy line directly on terminals. As soon as you say, I will dump terminal output with screen, and then parse the dump file, you loose the simplicity of write (and also need disk space, with the problem of removing old lines from a sequencial file)

Worse, as your script lives on its own, it could (should?) be a daemon script attached to no terminal

So if I have correctly understood your question, your requirements are:

- a script that does some tasks and should be able to respond to asynchronous requests - common usages are named pipes or network or unix domain sockets, less common are files in a dedicated folder with a optional signal to have immediate processing, adding lines to a sequential file while being possible is uncommon, because of a synchonization of access problem
- a *simple and convivial way* for users to pass requests. Ok `write` is nice for that part, but much too hard to interface IMHO

If you do not want to waste time on that part by using standard tools, I would recommend the mail system. It is trivial to alias a mail address to a program that will be called with the mail message as input. But I am not sure it is worth it, because the user could directly call the program with the request as input or command line parameter.

So the client part could be simply a program that:

- create a temporary file in a dedicated folder (`mkstemp` is your friend in C or C++, or `mktemp` in shell - but beware of race conditions)
- write the request to that file
- optionaly send a signal to a pid - provided the script write its own PID on startup to a dedicated file